# Finding out the probability distribution of numbers from -3 to 3

Tags: probability-distributions

I am really able to solve problems with the help of all the volunteers here.

a big thanks to every one..

Please explain this problem..

---

A random variable 'X' takes the values -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3. Such that  P(X=0) = P(X<0) = P(X>0) and P(X=-3) = P(X=-2) = P(X=-1) and P(X=3) = P(X=2) = P(X=1). Obtain the distribution of X.

---

I have found that P(X=0) = 1/7;
and now how to proceed...

Comment: Let the probability that $x=-3$ be $a$. Then everybody has probability $a$, except $0$, who has probability $3a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found it incorrectly. The first condition tells us that 
$$
  P(X = 0) = P(X > 0) = P(X < 0) =\frac13
$$
since the sum of these three probabilities is $1$. For other $6$ points, probabilities are $\frac19$.

Comment: Okay, so
P(X=0)+P(X<0)+P(X<0) = 1

Thank you..

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu: glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Set $p_{-3}=p_{-2}=p_{-1}=a$ and $p_{3}=p_{2}=p_{1}=b$ then:

$$3a+p_{0}+3b=1$$

$$3a=p_{0}=3b$$

Comment: Thank you @drhab, a different approach and how to find out the value of P(X=0)??

Comment: Here $P(X=0)$ is denoted as $p_0$ and with these equations you can find $3p_0=3a+p_0+3b=1$ hence $p_0=\frac{1}{3}$.